# Swift wait for an async function to be finished in order to start a new function

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

I am building an iOS app and I am downloading some data from Parse.

An overview:

1. I have a function which downloads the objectId from parse
2. I have an other function which downloads the rest of the details according to the object it, and it stores all the objects into an array
3. A last function which shows the appropriate outlets according to the size of the array.

The array of objects: 
`var meetings: [Meeting] = []`

The method which downloads the objectId:

```
func getTheUpcomingMeetings() {
    // The query
    let query = PFQuery(className: "UserMetting")
    // Find objects where the userId is equal to the user's id
    query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)
    query.orderByAscending("date")
    // Block to find the objects
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        // If there was no error
        if error == nil {
            // Get the array of Strings
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                // For each meeting id in the array of Strings
                for object in objects {
                    if let meetingId = object["meetingId"] as? String {
                        // Get the meeting details and append this meeting
                        self.getMeetingDetails(meetingId) // Call the other function
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

The method which gets the rest of the details and append the object into the array:

```
func getMeetingDetails(meetingId: String) {
    // The query to get the meeting
    let meetingQuery = PFQuery(className: "Meeting")
    // Find the meeting where the object id is equal to the argument which is passed into the method
    meetingQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: meetingId)
    // Find the objects
    meetingQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        // If there is no error
        if error == nil {
            // Get the array of PFObjects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                // For each object
                for object in objects {
                    // Create a new meeting
                    let meeting = Meeting(id: object.objectId!, name: object["name"] as! String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((object["location"]?.latitude)!, (object["location"]?.longitude)!), day: object["dayTime"] as! NSDate)
                    // Append this meeting into the array of meetings
                    self.meetings.append(meeting)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The last method which shows the appropriate outlets:

```
func showTheAppropriateOutlets() {
    // If there is no meeting
    if meetings.count == 0 {
        // Remove the outlets which refer to the meeting
        upcomingMeetingLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        mapView.removeFromSuperview()
        invitedUsersButton.removeFromSuperview()
        dayLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        day.removeFromSuperview()
        timeLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        time.removeFromSuperview()
        // Add a label to inform the user that there is no meeting
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200))
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByClipping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = UIColor(red: 250, green: 237, blue: 198, alpha: 1)
        label.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.center.y)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "There is no upcoming meeting. Create one!"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Bradley Hand", size: 35)
        view.addSubview(label)
    } else {

        // Set the outlets' text
        self.name.text = self.meetings[0].name
        self.day.text = getTheDay(self.meetings[0].day)
        self.time.text = getTheTime(self.meetings[0].day)
        // Show the location on the map view
        showTheLocationOnTheMap(self.meetings[0].location)
    }
}
```

The function which downloads the objectIds is called on the viewWillAppear function:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    getTheUpcomingMeetings()
}
```

I want to call the `showTheAppropriateOutlets()` function when the download of all the objects has been finished.

How can I achieve that??

Thanks in advance!!! :)

Comment: By putting the call to it right after `self.meetings.append(meeting)  }`

Comment: Using this way, if there is no objectId returned from the first function, this method will not be called :/

Comment: well, then add a call to it there as well. There is no silver bullet here, you have to just implement the logic for the call *exactly* as you want it to be.

Comment: Is there any way to wait for both functions to be finished?? I have found the following link http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/ for using dispatch groups

Comment: that will end up being the exactly same.

Comment: The point is that I have to wait for the functions to be finished because I want to sort the array when it is filled.

Comment: No, you do not want to wait for the functions to finish, but for the async tasks executed inside of them. Like I said: no silver bullet, write your logic.

Comment: So, I will put the method call after the append. If there is no objectId where should I put the function call again??